# Dynamically create sortable menuSubItems in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, sortablejs

I have a Shiny app using the `shinydashboard` package in which I'm dynamically creating `menuSubItem`s in the `sidebarMenu` of a `dashboardSidebar`. The creation of the subItems is triggered by an actionButton. I can create the `menuSubItem`s on the server side just fine, but I would like to also make them sortable using the `sortable` package and `sortable_js` function. I just can't seem to figure out where to place the `sortable_js` function to make this actually work, though.

Here's my MRE:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(sortable)

# Define UI for shinydashboard
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("tab_one", tabName = "test_body"),
        menuItemOutput("test"),
        id = "sidebar"
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItem("test_body",
              actionButton("click_me", "Click Me"))
    )
  )


# Define server logic to dynamically create menuSubItems
server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$click_me, {
    tabs_list <-
      lapply(1:5, function(x) {
        menuSubItem(text = paste("tab", x))
      })

    output$test <- renderMenu({
      menuItem("test_tabs", do.call(tagList, tabs_list))
    })
    sortable_js("test_tabs")
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sortable_js()` function generates HTML, so it’ll need to be included in the UI. However, you also have to make sure it is included after the element that it applies to already exists; it won’t work otherwise. Here, we can accomplish that by adding it to the output of the `renderMenu()` call as an additional child of the menu item created with `menuItem()`:

```r
output$test <- renderMenu({
  menu <- menuItem("test_tabs", do.call(tagList, tabs_list))
  tagAppendChildren(menu, sortable_js("test_tabs"))
})
```

Now, the id that you give to `sortable_js()` has to be the CSS id of the element whose children you want to make sortable. In this case, that would be the `ul` element inside the `menuItem()`, which contains all of the sub-items. Unfortunately there is no way to directly set this id when creating the menu item, so we have to inject it after the fact. A quick inspection of the `menuItem()` source code reveals that the `ul` tag is the second child of the menu item tag:

```r
output$test <- renderMenu({
  menu <- menuItem("test_tabs", do.call(tagList, tabs_list))
  menu$children[[2]] <- tagAppendAttributes(menu$children[[2]], id = "test_tabs")
  tagAppendChildren(menu, sortable_js("test_tabs"))
})
```

With these modifications, your example will be up and running:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(sortable)

# Define UI for shinydashboard
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("tab_one", tabName = "test_body"),
      menuItemOutput("test")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItem("test_body", actionButton("click_me", "Click Me"))
  )
)

# Define server logic to dynamically create menuSubItems
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$click_me, {
    tabs_list <- lapply(1:5, function(x) {
      menuSubItem(text = paste("tab", x))
    })

    output$test <- renderMenu({
      menu <- menuItem("test_tabs", do.call(tagList, tabs_list))
      menu$children[[2]] <- tagAppendAttributes(menu$children[[2]], id = "test_tabs")
      tagAppendChildren(menu, sortable_js("test_tabs"))
    })
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>